# how to learn python linguistic in general : data = {i : randn() for i in range(7)}

Tags: python

I have trouble learning python by reading examples on line or in the book.2nd line, For example

```
from numpy.random import randn
data = {i : randn() for i in range(7)}
```

I run it on the jupyter get the result but still dont know how it works. Any suggestion for me to understand this code and how do I lean how python runs

Comment: This is a "dictionary comprehension" if that helps you find some relevant tutorials online.

Comment: This is basically saying, "for each *i* in the inclusive range [0, 6], *i*'s corresponding value in the dictionary is a random number." The key: value mapping is `i: random number`...

Comment: why don't understand ? Source and target are same and using more `temp` values. `data = {}` and `data={ generator_object}` is same !

Answer (score 1):

It's called Dict Comprehension ([PEP 274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)) and its basically a follow up to List Comprehension ([PEP 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)). The [Rationale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#id5) of it is:

> List comprehensions provide a more concise way to create lists in
>   situations where map() and filter() and/or nested loops would
>   currently be used.

Your code:

```
data = {i : randn() for i in range(7)}
```

Can be read as:

```
data = {}
for i in range(7):
    data[i] = randn()
```

But this was an idiomatic choice, not something you could just assume from the second example. Think of it as a faster way to create a container of something. If you are starting to learn Python now, start with the common loops and syntax and when you understand those concepts you can jump to [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) stuff.